# Can the identity of convolution be derived? Or is the only way to guess?

Tags: distribution-theory, convolution

The dirac delta distribution is the identity under convolution. Is there a way we can derive this result without defining the dirac delta function pre-hand and testing it?

Comment: You could simply say that the dirac delta is defined to be the (generalized) function which makes the identity in question hold.

Comment: How do you know such a distribution exists?

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables with distributions $\mu$, and $\nu$, then $\mu * \nu$ is the distribution of $X + Y$. From this it is clear that the dirac measure is the identity for convolution, as it is the distribution of $0$.