# How do we prove a distribution identity exists?

Tags: distribution-theory, convolution

Let's say we didn't know about the Dirac Delta distribution.

How could we prove that, if $f$ is integrable over $\mathbb{R}^n$, there exists a tempered distribution $d$ such that when convoluted with $f,$ $(f*d)(t) = f(t)$?

Comment: Isn't this essentially the same question as the one you just asked? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4520657/can-the-identity-of-convolution-be-derived-or-is-the-only-way-to-guess

Comment: That's a different question. That question is asking to derive an explicit structure. This question is asking whether one simply exists at all. This question is more general and easier than being asked to find a specific structure.

Comment: Do you know what a distribution is?

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC I have a rough idea of what a distribution is. Certainly not a function, but an object which is integrable over the whole domain space. Suppose we didn't know about the Dirac Delta distribution. How do we prove an identity exists in the space of tempered distributions?

Comment: So, distributions are *defined* as operators that take in (certain types of) functions and return real numbers, and are continuous wrt a certain topology on that space of functions. The map $T(f) =f(0)$ turns functions into numbers, is linear, and (once you nail down all the topological details) is continuous.

Comment: Now, a lot of distributions arise from integrating the input function against some fixed function, and you might want to find a fixed function that implements the $T$ we just defined. But we can prove that that's not possible. The best we can do is find a sequence of functions whose induced distributions converge to our $T$ (again, once we nail down some topological details).

Comment: It's kind of like how the axioms of the real numbers show that there is a positive number that squares to $2$, but since we can only write down a finite number of decimals at one time, all we can do is get arbitrarily close to it by taking more digits of 1.41421....

Comment: I have a concept of what a distribution is, I also know what an approximate identity is, the object you're alluding to. I'm asking how you can prove there exists an element $d$ in the space of tempered distributions over $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $f*d = f$ without explicitly knowing what the identity is.

Answer (score 0):

The Dirac Delta distribution is DEFINED in a way that would satisfy your search.
If by (f*d)(t) you are defining a convolution integral over the whole real line then the delta distribution picks the value of f at zero but in the equation you have highlighted, it could be shifted to the value ‘t’ so your equation by definition gives the value at ‘t’ i.e. the unit impulse is at t rather than 0.

If I am right, Laurent Schwarz (Fields Medallist and Alexander Grothendieck’s doctoral adviser) showed that such a delta could NOT exist as an ordinary ‘function’ but he generalised functions to ‘distributions’ so that your equation is satisfied by definition. In doing so he also provided a rigorous basis for Dirac’s Delta function which was more of an ad-hoc (but genius)construction.

Comment: You can define an identity that satisfies the properties you desire, that doesn't mean such an identity exists. Let's say we didn't know the Dirac Delta function existed. How would we prove *some* distribution, in general, does exist?